# Как реализовать отправку данных с формы на сайте в GA? через gtag

Tags: google-analytics

- action - send
- event_category - form
- event_label - XXXXXXXXXX //номер телефона

Помогите пожалуйста с кодом.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Что не так с примерами из документации? [Send data to Google Analytics with gtag.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/sending-data)